# TP-Link connection breaks on Cisco VPN traffic

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

Configuration:

- Windows 7 64-bit notebook
- TL-WR1043ND hw rev V1 fw 3.13.13 (should be the latest)
- Cisco VPN 5.0.07.0290

This setup worked like a charm until today. Suddenly it became unstable: whenever I try to transfer something 5+M. Of course, the VPN breaks. Afterwards the notebook can still communicate with the router but not beyond (i.e. the WAN). The workaround is to reboot the router.

The problem seems to have started upon the first DHCP renewal by the router (as a client) with the ISP (as the server) but neither rebooting the cable modem nor rebooting the router solved the issue.

The problem doesn't seem to be present if I transfer same files without the Cisco VPN. Previously it happened with another Windows 7 notebook but without a Cisco VPN and it was not so persistent (perhaps one reboot per week).

I'm assuming it's due to an incompatibility between the router and Cisco VPN, or maybe the router and Windows 7 but how can I identify which party is responsible? Once I know what the cause is, what is the fix?

**EDIT:** when this occurs, the notebook can access the admin GUI of the router but other functions like DHCP renew or DNS lookup all fail. According to the router logs, it receives "DHCP INFORM" but does not send "DHCP ACK". According to Wireshark, however, the router does send "DHCP ACK".

**EDIT:** it seems that there's another player: the problem only happens if the traffic is generated by a VMWare virtual machine (using a NAT between the host and guest).

**EDIT (the solution):** it was caused by Cisco using UDP which made TP-Link DOS protection ("Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering") kick in and block the notebook's IP completely.

I found the relevant settings in the Cisco VPN: Modify / Transport / IPSec over TCP (instead of IPSec over UDP).

The relevant settings for the TP-Link are: Security / Advanced Security / Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering.

A workaround in the same place: click "Blocked DoS host list" and then click "clear" if you find your IP inside.

Comment: Found solution! it was caused by Cisco using UDP which made TP-Link DOS "Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering" to kick in and block the notebook's IP completely. Relevant settings in Cisco VPN: Modify / Transport / IPSec over TCP (instead of IPSec over UDP). Relevant settings in TP-Link: Security / Advanced Security / Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering. Workaround in same place: click "Blocked DoS host list" and then click "clear" if you find your IP inside. Someone with appropriate rights could please close this question (I need no score for answering my own questions ;) )

Comment: I have a TP-Link Archer D2 router but I don't see the Advanced Security menu anywhere. Any idea how I can get to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(now trying to close it for real!)

It was caused by Cisco using UDP which made TP-Link DOS "Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering" to kick in and block the notebook's IP completely.

Relevant settings in Cisco VPN: Modify / Transport / IPSec over TCP (instead of IPSec over UDP).

Relevant settings in TP-Link: Security / Advanced Security / Enable UDP-FLOOD Filtering.

Workaround in same place: click "Blocked DoS host list" and then click "clear" if you find your IP inside.