# TP-Link Archer D2 DoS Attack settings not visible anywhere

Tags: router

I have a TP-Link Archer D2 and when I connect to a client's VPN via Cisco Anyconnect it keeps dropping the internet connection.

I did some searching and came across this post: [TP-Link connection breaks on Cisco VPN traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/686862/tp-link-connection-breaks-on-cisco-vpn-traffic)

This seems like the right answer, but I can't find the settings on the router to disable DoS Attack settings to prove that this is in fact the problem.

On the manufacturer website I found links like these: http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1533.html, that suggest going to **Advanced > Security > Settings** where I should find the **DoS protection** switch. But under **Advanced > Security** I only have **Access Control** and **IP & MAC Binding** sub-menus.

Anyone know how I can disable DoS protection or why I can't see these advanced settings?

Comment: The article doesn't apply to your product

Comment: Thanks. I've since been in touch with TP-Link. They're trying to help me figure out what's going on.